# php - dynamic mysql_query in for loop from url array

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I've looked for something similar on stack but nothing exactly as this.

I (think I) need to generate a unique MySQL query inside a loop as each iteration needs to look up a different table. the loop is from an exploded $_GET array.

The problem is creating a differently named mysql query based on the loop iteration. I've done it where the $var name is different but it doesn't work, I think because it is a string not a variable?

Any help appreciated

```
$temps = explode(",", $_GET['temps']);
$tempCount = count($temps); 

for ($i=0; $i<$tempCount; $i++)
{
/*'normal' database lookup
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _db_".$temps[$i]."");       
    $checks = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
    $checks[] = $row;
    }*/


//here's where I'm trying to build a 'dynamic' lookup for each loop iteration

$checkTemp=$check.$temps[$i];
$checkTempArray=$check.$temps[$i].'Array';

$checkTemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _db_".$temps[$i]."");       
    $checkTempArray = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkTemp)) {
    $checkTempArray[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: $check is not being used

Comment: What do you mean by a 'differently named' MySQL query?

Comment: I've amended it so you can see that the db table name is different for each iteration. So the array that needs to be stored has to have a different name for later lookup (foreach,etc). Eg arrays $checkJohn and $checkSally

Comment: $checkTemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _db_".$temp[$i]."");   either use $temps[$i] or just $temp, $temp[$i] doesn't makes any sense

Comment: Thanks, I've amended that. But I need to create a dynamically created array, too, for later lookup. That's my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to `SELECT *` from all tables seperated by `,` in the `$_GET["temps"]`

```
$temps = explode(",", $_GET['temps']);
$tempCount = count($temps); 

$allResults = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$tempCount; $i++)
{
    $checkTemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _db_".mysql_real_escape_string($temps[$i]));
    $allResults[$temps[$i]] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkTemp))
    {
        $allResults[$temps[$i]][] = $row;
    }
}
// Now for example $allResults["john"][3] contains the fourth row in the table _db_john
print_r($allResults["sally"][2]); // print the third row in _db_sally
```

Comment: Hi. I've amended my code to show the _db appended with the temp variable. so the url '&temps=john,sally' will look up _db_john and _db_sally

Comment: @gavin I changed my answer, it now stores the results in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo in your code

```
$checkTemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db".$temp[$i]."");
```

either use

```
$temps[$i] or just  $temp 
$temp[$i] doesn't makes any sense
```

so your query should be instead

```
$checkTemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db".$temps[$i]."");
```

EDIT:
for your array part you can use

```
 $$temp = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkTemp)) {
    $$temp[] = $row;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,boom_Shiva. I've amended that now. I need to create a dynamically created array, too, for later lookup. That doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've simplified it, just using $temps[i].